# How to select distinct on multiple columns in Sparql?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

```
query1:
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/> 
SELECT distinct ?y as ?r1 distinct ?x0 as ?r0 WHERE {
      ?x1 ?x0 :m.0qj89jg. 
      ?x1 ?y ?x2 .
      FILTER regex(?x0, "http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/")
      FILTER regex(?y, "http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/")
 }

query2:
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/> 
SELECT distinct ?y as ?r1 ?x0 as ?r0 WHERE {
      ?x1 ?x0 :m.0qj89jg. 
      ?x1 ?y ?x2 .
      FILTER regex(?x0, "http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/")
      FILTER regex(?y, "http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/")
 }
```

The first query got a syntax error and the second query returns all distinct (y, x0) pairs. What I want is to get all distinct values of y and all distinct values of x0 (not distinct pairs of (y, x0), as they are considered independently). I believe this shouldn't be hard, but I couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: that's not possible (or at least I don't see how) - you should go the other way around, use a `UNION` and then some second marker variable which denotes whether it's about `?x0` or `?y`

Comment: @AKSW Thanks! Do you know what's the best way to get all adjacent relations (both directions are considered) within 2 hops of a given entity? Now I need to run for different queries corresponding to 4 cases (i.e., in relation and out relation, in and in, out and out, out and in)

Comment: you could wrap all those in a single query with 4 `UNION` clauses or not? Like `SELECT DISTINCT ?p { {:x ?p1 ?o . ?o ?p ?o1} UNION {:x ?p1 ?o . ?s ?p ?o} UNION {?s ?p1 :x . ?s ?p ?o} UNION {?s ?p1 :x . ?s1 ?p ?s }}` for a given resource `:x`